# MongoDB (pymongo): $in for fields "tuples" with multiple possibilities

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to find records in my mongo collection by applying some sort of a `$in` operator but in multiple fields (logical AND)

#### Example:

Assuming I have the following records in a collection named `items`:

```
[
    {
        "key": 'a';
        "value": 'b';
        "etc": 'foo';
    },
    {
        "key": 'x';
        "value": 'y';
        "etc": 'bar';
    },
    {
        "key": 'a';
        "value": 'y';
        "etc": 'jazz';
    }
]
```

Now I want to execute something like:

```
db.items.find_all({"key, value": {"$in": [("a", "b"), ("x", "y")]}})
```

Which would yield the result records:

```
[
    {
        "key": 'a';
        "value": 'b';
        "etc": 'foo';
    },
    {
        "key": 'x';
        "value": 'y';
        "etc": 'bar';
    }
]
```

Is there anything similar to that? or a way to manipulate `$in` to achieve that output?
Thank you very much

Comment: You could map the tuples to objects with key/values properties and then use $or. https://mongoplayground.net/p/VuxYl_wbCpW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$in` is not right tool for the job. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/ clearly states it is for single field only.

You should be fine with old plain "or" unless I miss something in your requirements:

```
the_list = [("a", "b"), ("x", "y")]
db.items.find_all({"$or": [{"key":t[0], "value":t[1]} for t in the_list]} )
```